# How can I prune a (kmz) track from my GPS?

Tags: editing, trackpoint, gps

I want to keep a track from a walk the other day. When I stopped walking and got into a taxi, I forgot to turn the GPS off immediately, and now I want to prune away all of the taxi track.

I've done something similar manually before, by deleting individual data points from the text file, but now it's a bit too hard.

I have tried GpsPrune and JGPSTrackEdit without any success. Here are some images:

Original kmz in Google Earth: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqNzC.jpg

Original kml in Google Earth: https://i.stack.imgur.com/maZx0.jpg

Original kmz in GpsPrune (only start and end points show): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD1V0.jpg

Original kml in GpsPrune (only start and end points show): https://i.stack.imgur.com/db26w.jpg

Original kmz opened in JGPSTrackEdit (nothing appeared): https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7U8s.jpg

Original kml opened in JGPSTrackEdit (nothing appeared): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnD4X.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The `kmz` are KML files **Z**ipped (compressed).

Make a copy of the file, and rename the extension.

`cp myfile.kmz myfile.zip`

Unzip it.

`unzip myfile.zip` or with an 'archive' application.

Locate the file `doc.kml` and open it with your favourite text editor, or install an xml editor such as `XML Copy Editor` because `doc.kml` is an `xml` file.

Locate the data you no longer want.  Typically it will be between the tags `<coordinates>` and `</coordinates>`

Delete it.

There may be additional artefacts that you may, or will, want to delete. Such as

`<LineString  id="g7">
<altitudeMode>clampedToGround</altitudeMode>
<coordinates>-115.478882259744,32.8305154499076,1 
-115.47919506463,32.8301376995818,1 
</coordinates>
</LineString>`

As long are there are no dangling or unmatched tags, and the final file contains enough of the requisite information you will have a usable `kml` file.

It's your decision if you should compress it again into a `kmz`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Nodak.

Yes that is the method that I've used before (when I said "I've done something similar manually before"). I tried it again this time, but it's a bit too hard, because:

(a) I haven't been able to identify the data that you refer to as "the data you no longer want", which is the times and coordinates that are not relevant; and

(b) "There may be additional artefacts that you may, or will, want to delete" and "As long..." - I don't really want to spend the time on trial-and-error if I know that it might not end happily (ie. successfully).